# get timezone in "+0100" (for example) format

Tags: java, timezone, datetime-format

I got lost between the documentation and the numerous time-related questions found by google.

What I want is very simple: a string that represents the running timezone in the
"[+/-] [number] [number] [number] [number]" 
format (for instance "+0100").

My current code is:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
    String gmt = "" + tz.getID();
```

which returns "GMT" in my location, which I assume is the short version (3 letters) of the timezones.

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code I actually ended up using, I hope it helps someone.

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
String gmt = sdf.format(today);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try following thing.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("current: " + c.getTime());

        TimeZone z = c.getTimeZone();
        int offset = z.getRawOffset();
        if (z.inDaylightTime(new Date())) {
            offset = offset + z.getDSTSavings();
        }
        int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;

        System.out.println("offset: " + offsetHrs);
        System.out.println("offset: " + offsetMins);

        c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (-offsetHrs));
        c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-offsetMins));

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        System.out.println("GMT Time: " + sdf.format(c.getTime()) + " +"
                + offsetHrs + ":" + offsetMins);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
current: Wed May 16 22:32:14 IST 2012
offset: 5
offset: 30
GMT Time: 2012-05-16 17:02:14 +5:30
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Actually I do not need the date (which is defined by the user in the context of a graph request), just the GMT code. :) I have one question, though: what if the timezone is "negative"?

Comment: Then it will be displayed in negative format. And you can get the timezone value from `offsetHrs` and `offsetMins`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want "Z" or "X" in SimpleDateFormat

```
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```

Comment: I actually liked your approach, but it would have been nice if you've showed me some alternative code. I will add my current code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace ZoneId as applicable e.g. ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("XX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String offset = dtf.format(now);
        System.out.println(offset);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
+0100
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

Feedback from Ole V.V.:

> You may want to use lower case `xx` so you also get `+0000` rather than
> `Z` for offset zero.

Thanks, Ole V.V. for the value addition which will benefit someone looking for `+0000` rather than `Z` for a zero-timezone offset. I recommend using this strictly based on the specific requirement. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) recommends using `Z` as the timezone designator for a zero-timezone offset.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: You may want to use lower case `xx` so you also get `+0000` rather than ´Z` for offset zero.